# File corrupt after BinaryRead/Write / FileStream.Read/Write /File.Read/WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I'm doing file encrypt/decrypt application and stuck for a long time.
I can't believe it gonna be this hard just to read and write files.

Here's the variable

```
    byte[] FileBytes = null; //file bytes
    byte[] KeyBytes = null; //key bytes
    byte[] ResBytes = null; //result bytes
```

Read all bytes from the file

```
    private void ReadFile()
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(this.txtFilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
        {
            int x = 0;

            this.FileBytes = new byte[(int)br.BaseStream.Length];
            int length = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

            while (x < length)
            {
                this.FileBytes[x] = br.ReadByte();

                x++;
            }

            br.Close();
        }
    }
```

Write the file

```
    private void WriteFile()
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(this.OutputPath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            // 3. Use foreach and write all 12 integers.
            foreach (byte b in this.ResBytes)
            {
                bw.Write(b);
            }

            bw.Flush();
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Encryption method

```
    public byte ApplyVernam(byte inByte, byte keyByte)
    {
        if (inByte == keyByte) { return inByte; }
        else { return (byte)(inByte ^ keyByte); }
    }
```

And here's the execute button click event (I put FileBytes[1] as key) and yes, the file corrupted except for text document. I thought BinaryWriter is good to do file encryption, but why it's not working? Something wrong in my code?
I need explanation here.
Thank you very much.

```
    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.ReadFile();
            this.ResBytes = new byte[this.FileBytes.Length];

            int x = 0;

            while (x < this.FileBytes.Length)
            {
                this.ResBytes[x] = this.ApplyVernam(this.FileBytes[x], this.FileBytes[1]);
                x++;
            }

            this.WriteFile();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're just loading and saving the entire contents into `byte` arrays, why are you fiddling around with streams? Why not just use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Cause that thing can't work, I tried so many times already. Can you suggest me other method that work?

Comment: It's not the file access method that's corrupting the files - it's your encryption and decryption routines. Simplify everything by just having a `byte[256]` in your code that contains the bytes 0-255. Unless and until you can encrypt this array and then decrypt it back into it's original form, don't even mess about with reading and writing files.

Comment: You're definitely right, I listed all the bytes into data grid and compare the bytes (before/after encrypt/decrypt), I realize that my encryption had weakness. 0 meet 75 = 75 and when 75 meet 75 = 75. To fix this I put if zero then the byte stay zero no matter what the key is. The weakness is that my encryption can't encrypt 0 char in text document. It will stay zero. Thank you very much again. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: A better fix would be, as Iridium indicated, take out that special casing that you're currently doing for `inByte==keyByte` - that way 0 could become 75 because 75 would become 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your encryption method is not invertible, and so you cannot reliably decrypt a general binary message with it. The problem occurs because it is possible for two different plaintext values to encrypt to the same ciphertext value, and when this happens there's no way for you to determine when decrypting which was the correct input value.

Example:

```
if inByte = 100 and keyByte = 100:
    ApplyVernam(100, 100) = 100

if inByte = 0, keyByte = 100:
    ApplyVernam(0, 100) = 100
```

It's now impossible to tell whether the original plaintext byte was `0` or `100` when trying to decrypt.

I would suggest removing the line: `if (inByte == keyByte) { return inByte; }` from your `ApplyVernam` method so that it always `XORs` the input with the key and so is fully invertible.

As mentioned in my comment, your "key" is the byte at position 1 in the input, but this is also being encrypted, and so when you decrypt, the byte at position 1 is no longer the original key. Changing the following line may resolve the issue:

From:

```
this.ResBytes[x] = this.ApplyVernam(this.FileBytes[x], this.FileBytes[1]);
```

To:

```
this.ResBytes[x] = x == 1 ? this.FileBytes[x] : this.ApplyVernam(this.FileBytes[x], this.FileBytes[1]);
```

This will ensure that the key byte is written unencrypted to the output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I add that line of code because without that, both word document and text document not working. I will remove that, and yet my problem still unsolved. @Iridium

Comment: @vkstarry Your key appears to be derived from the plaintext byte at position 1. Assuming you use the same method for encryption and decryption, the value at position 1 in the ciphertext will always be zero (since anything `XOR`-ed with itself is zero). Since you then presumably use this byte as the key when decrypting, it will fail because it wasn't the same value used to encrypt. I shall edit my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you, but I think file encryption still matters, should I change to another read / write method? Maybe binary reader/writer not compatible for encryption. @Iridium

Comment: You're definitely right, I listed all the bytes into data grid and compare the bytes (before/after encrypt/decrypt), I realize that my encryption had weakness. 0 meet 75 = 75 and when 75 meet 75 = 75. To fix this I put if zero then the byte stay zero no matter what the key is. The weakness is that my encryption can't encrypt 0 char in text document. It will stay zero. Thank you very much again. @Iridium